# Retrieve historical stock valuation data with python

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, stocks

I am looking to retrieve historical data like P/E ratio, earnings, book value etc as well as stock price. I'd like to go through a whole bunch of stocks programmatically or to possibly select historical stocks based on valuation rules.

I found a few python packages to download historical stock prices from Yahoo like [yahoo-finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) and also this guide to downloading historical prices with [the browser](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/yahoo-finance-hidden-api/). But I could not find anything to download historical valuation data.

I am aware of [Survivorship Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) problem with the stocks that affects these free services but I can't afford a paid one right now.

Comment: Have you tried to use that library? Where are you stuck?

Comment: They don't have historical P/E just current, for example.

Comment: Ah, programmatically, maybe the wolfram alpha api could help... This Reddit has some sources you could use. https://m.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/1gnlaw/where_to_find_historical_eps_and_pe_ratios/